# How to select all rows from group, until occurrence of a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to extract all rows from same `Group` until I hit breakpoint value `B`. The example data below is ordered virtual table:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | Group  | Breakpoint |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | A          |
| 2  | 1      | A          |
| 3  | 1      | B          |
| 4  | 1      | A          |
| 5  | 2      | A          |
| 6  | 2      | A          |
| 7  | 2      | A          |
| 8  | 3      | A          |
| 9  | 3      | B          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

This would be my result.

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | Group  | Breakpoint |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | A          |
| 2  | 1      | A          |
| 5  | 2      | A          |
| 6  | 2      | A          |
| 7  | 2      | A          |
| 8  | 3      | A          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Notice that when there are both `A` and `B` breakpoint values within a group, I want to have the rows until the first `A` value in this order. If there are only `A` values for a group like in `group 2`, I want to have all of the items in the group.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Sorry, it was a virtual table result, I did add a unique key in the example above!

Comment: Maybe if we start at the beginning....

Comment: What server/ Db are you using? and why ID four is excluded?

Comment: @TommyO:  `id=4` didn't make it into the expected output, because there is a preceding row `id=3` (for the same `group`) that has `breakpoint='B'`. I think OP wants to *stop* at the last row before the first 'B'. I think that's why OP is labeling that column as "breakpoint". When we hit the first 'B', we "break"; we are done with that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that uses no subqueries or GROUP BY logic.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Group, t1.Breakpoint
FROM MyTable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS t2
  ON t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t1.`Group` = t2.`Group` AND t2.Breakpoint = 'B'
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

For each row `t1`, try to find another row `t2` with 'B', in the same Group, with an earlier ID. If none is found, the OUTER JOIN guarantees that `t2.ID` is NULL. That will be true only up until the desired breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

From you example above, you are not really grouping the results. you just need to display the records where Breakpoint is A:

```
Select * From Table
Where Breakpint ='A'
```

Comment: Note that this query would return row `id=4`, which is excluded from OP example output.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select *
from your_table t1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from your_table t2
  where t1.group = t2.group and t2.id <= t1.id and t2.breakpoint = 'B'
)
```

or `ALL` can work as well if you never have `NULL` in `id`

```
select *
from your_table t1
where t1.id < ALL(
  select t2.id
  from your_table t2
  where t1.group = t2.group and t2.breakpoint = 'B'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no "before" or "after" a particular row.

Let me assume that you have some column that specifies the ordering.  I'll call it `id`.  You can then do what you want with:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id < (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.group = t.group and t2.breakpoint = 'B');
```

To get all rows when if there are no `'B'`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id < (select coalesce(min(t2.id), t.id + 1) from t t2 where t2.group = t.group and t2.breakpoint = 'B');
```

Comment: When there are no rows with `breakpoint = 'B'`, looks like OP wants to return all of the rows. I think this query excludes those rows. (See `group=2` rows in OP sample data, and expected output.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are ordering by `ID` column, we could do something like this:

```
 SELECT d.*
   FROM mytable d
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT bp.group
               , MIN(bp.id) AS bp_id
            FROM mytable bp
           WHERE bp.breakpoint = 'B'
           GROUP BY bp.group
        ) b
     ON b.group = d.group
  WHERE b.bp_id > d.id OR b.bp_id IS NULL 
  ORDER BY d.group, d.id
```

---

This takes into account cases where there is no `breakpoint='B'` row for a given `group`, and returns all of the rows for that `group`.

Note that the inline view `b` gets us the lowest `id` value from rows with `breakpoint='B'` for each `group`. We can outer join that to original table (matching on `group`), and then conditional tests in the WHERE clause to exclude rows that follow the first `breakpoint='B'` for each group.